# Check When MY Oracle Password Expires

Tags: oracle, passwords

I have a non-admin login to an Oracle database, and I'd like to check when my password expires. I've found a lot of information online about getting password expiration dates by querying on the `DBA_USERS` table -- but I do not have privileges to view that table.

I'm hopeful that Oracle includes a way for me to check password expiration for my own login, but so far I've been unable to find any queries *except* those that reference the `DBA_USERS` table.

Is there a way for me to determine when my own password expires without putting in a ticket to the DBA?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can see the current user details using

```
select * from USER_USERS;
```

That will have a column name "expiry_date" which has the data you ask for.

P.S.
For almost every DBA_* there is an ALL_* (all the permitted records that the current user can see) and a USER_* (all the permitted records owned by the current user)

so DBA_TABLES has all the tables the systems has, ALL_TABLES has all the tables the current user has permissions to do something on (update, delete, insert, modify, etc), and USER_TABLES - all the tables the current user created.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you! (I can't accept the answer for 5 more minutes, but I will when I can.)

Comment: You're welcomed :) - I added a short explanation about the USER, ALL, and DBA prefixes.. might help you in the future :)

Comment: `USER_USERS` won't have `PASSWORD` and `PROFILE ` information as compared to `DBA_USERS`.

Comment: `select * from dba_users;` shows all users the current user can see... if you are logged in as the DBA, for instance, this will show all database users. I know the answer says this, but as a non-expert Oracle user, this wasn't super clear, and I wasn't finding the info the OP mentioned. Instead I found this SO question and wanted the `select * from dba_users;` answer. So here it is.

Answer (score 5):

Completing the previous answer

```
select USERNAME,EXPIRY_DATE from USER_USERS;
```

will give you the same result but with less clustered and easier to read output.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a very detailed answer to this question for quite some time and now I finally found an answer.

If you would like to know EXACTLY when your password expires, use this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select username, expiry_date from user_users where username='my_username';
```

You will get results not just in date, but also in exact time.